# How does Swift handle if statements?

Tags: swift, logical-operators, short-circuiting

If I have the statement:

```
if object != nil && object.property == 2 {
    //do something
}
```

does the if statement break as soon as it finds out `object = nil`?

Comment: yes, short circuit evaluation is a common feature in most languages. See Logical operators in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

When you concatenate a list of conditions `C[0]`...`C[n]` with the AND `&&` operator, the runtime evaluates **in order** each condition and if a `C[i]` condition is found `false`, then the evaluation of the whole expression does end and it is judged `false`.

```
let c0 = true
let c1 = false
let c2 = true

if c0 && c1 && c2 {
    print("Hello world")
}
```

In this case only `c0` and `c1` will be evaluated and the whole expression will be interpreted as `false`.

You can test it yourself in Playground.

[image]

### c0 || c1 || c2

Symmetrically if you define an expression as the OR `||` concatenation of several clauses, then the whole expression is interpreted as `true` (and the evaluation of the clauses does stop) as soon as the first true condition gets found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is the answer.

Simple to try - see below - however note that as written your test won't work - a non-optional cannot be `nil`, and so you will have to unwrap it to test `.property`.

```
struct MyObj {
    var property: Int
}

var object: MyObj? = nil

if object != nil && object!.property == 2 {
    print("Not nil")
} else {
    print("Nil") // Prints - would have crashed if test fully evaluated
}

object = MyObj(property: 2)

if object != nil && object!.property == 2 {
    print("Not nil")  // Prints
} else {
    print("Nil")
}
```